# Finding the width of a control from inside the control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a user control that needs to set one of its variables based on the total width of the control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
   ...
    x:Name="MyControlRoot">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MyControlRoot}">
        <Canvas>
            <Ellipse Width="{Binding MyWidth}" Height="{Binding MyHeight}"
```

In the code behind, the properties are defined as follows:

```
    public double MyWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return (ActualWidth - 5);
        }
    }
```

I've tried `ActualWidth`, `Width` and even tried to access the width of the root element, but don't seem to be able to determine the width of the control at runtime; I either get 0, or NaN.

My question is: how do I access the width at runtime from within a control?

Comment: you can asses the actual width after layout is performed.

Comment: Can you try doing OnPropertyChanged("MyWidth") in the loaded event of the usercontrol? That will tell the control to set the width of the ellipse again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try this

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Path=ActualWidth}"
```

Comment: That's not quite what I want to do.  What I need is a way to access this in code, so that I can adjust it slightly.

Comment: You can adjust it using converters.

Comment: Would using a converter differ from simply binding to a property that references the ActualWidth?  Surely if the property isn't available then it still won't be?

Comment: ActualWidth is DependencyProperty so it informs about changes, Converter would be invoked first when created and then every time ActualWidth is changed. Try this otherwise you cannot find out.